# Where to put information about padding length?

Tags: encryption, aes, pkcs#7

I'm working on AES encryptor and decryptor. I've decided to use PKCS#7. And now, I've no idea where to put information about padding length. I've read that I can read last byte (==n) and check if it's lower than 16. If it's true i can check n bytes if they are equal n. But here is a thing. What if the last block to encrypt has 16 bytes and looks like this for exmaple:

```
{0x01, 0xfa,..., 0xf1, 0x02, 0x02}
```

After decryption, decryptor will read it and decide that two last bytes are padded (in fact they are not).

Should I add byte at the begining of a file with length, and decryptor will read it and start decrypting from second byte?

Comment: I think you'd normally just add an entire block of padding if your message size is exactly divisible by the block size.

Comment: @Damien And I think you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PKCS#7 padding is deterministic. That means that unpadding should always be able to find out the padding length itself. So you first decrypt, then take the last byte (as number) and that is the padding length. **For this to work, PKCS#7 padding is *always* applied. So the amount of padding, and thus the value of the bytes, is 1 to the blocksize, which is 16 bytes for AES.** . If the plaintext is already dividable by 16, a full block of padding - with bytes valued 16 / 0x10 is applied.

In short, the calculation is:

```
p = n - l % n
```

where `p` is the pad size & value, `n` is the block size and `l` is the size of the plaintext.

Comment: If you are worried about an attacker changing the last block of ciphertext, be sure to apply a HMAC.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is to add 32bit prefix with the actual length before encrypted data.

Comment: Why should it have 32 bits? Is it connected with integer size?

Comment: 32bit is standard size. If the blocks are always <64K and the space is inportant for you (e.g. embedded app) you can define 16 bit prefix as well.

Comment: Voted down, PKCS#7 is deterministic, it doesn't require the size to be known in advance. Knowing the size in advance *can* be useful, but it is not specifically required to perform PKCS#7 unpadding.

Comment: Ok. My comment was for (AES) encryption of variable length blocks in common case.