# Why does AES 128 encryption expanding the data?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, byte, aes

I used following code to encrypt the data. My input is 16 bytes and key is 16 bytes but the output I am getting (encrypted data ) is 32 bytes. Why?

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key)  {
try {
  byte[] passwordKey128 = Arrays.copyOfRange(key, 0, 16);
  SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey128, "AES");
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
  byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
  // String encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
  return cipherText;
```

What can be the reason? Does AES add some data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to put information about padding length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930911/where-to-put-information-about-padding-length)

Comment: According to standard, AES has a block size of 128 bits. In other words other block sizes are non-standard. You citation doesn't reveal what the function of the software developer "cipher.doFinal()" does. So, IMHO it's better to ask the developer of your software to explain the phenomenon you observed.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: It's the padding. You could use Cipher.getInstance("AES/xxx/NoPadding") where the cipher mode "xxx" can, for example, be CTR, CFB or OFB if you absolutely want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain `Cipher` object through the `Cipher.getInstance(transformation)` method where the transformation is of the form:

```
"algorithm/mode/padding" or
"algorithm"
```

When you do this the implementation searches through the list of crypto providers in the system and determine if any implementation supports this. If you don't specify the mode and padding, its up to the crypto provider to decide what default mode and padding to use.

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher), For example, the SunJCE defaults to ECB as the default mode, and **PKCS5Padding**.

As **PKCS5Padding** always adds at least one byte, it pushes your 16 bytes over the limit of the block and creates the need for two blocks.